# How to join three tables having relation parent-child-child's child. And I want to access all records related to parent

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables:

```
articles(id,title,message)
comments(id,article_id,commentedUser_id,comment)
comment_likes(id, likedUser_id, comment_id, action_like, action_dislike)
```

I want to show `comments.id, comments.commentedUser_id, comments.comment, ( Select count(action_like) where action_like="like") as likes and comment_id=comments.id where comments.article_id=article.id`

Actually I want to count all action_likes that related to any comment. And show all all comments of articles.
action_likes having only two values null or like

```
SELECT c.id , c.CommentedUser_id , c.comment , (cl.COUNT(action_like) WHERE action_like='like' AND comment_id='c.id') as likes 
      FROM comment_likes as cl 
      LEFT JOIN comments as c ON c.id=cl.comment_id 
      WHERE c.article_id=article.id
```

It shows nothing, I know I'm doing wrong way, that was just that I want say

Comment: Please add some sample data and expected output. Are you looking for same LIKE COUNT in each row? or looking for a GROUP BY option?

Comment: i want to show all comments related to an article and all likes relaed to a comment. i have just an article.id.

Comment: i want to show all comments related to an article and total action_likes that having value 'like' as likes relaed to a comment. i have just an article.id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like below. This will return Article/Comment wise LIKE count.

```
SELECT
a.id article_id,
c.id comment_id, 
c.CommentedUser_id , 
c.comment , 
COUNT (CASE WHEN action_like='like' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as likes 
FROM article a 
INNER JOIN comments C ON a.id = c.article_id
LEFT JOIN  comment_likes as cl  ON c.id=cl.comment_id 
GROUP BY a.id,c.id , c.CommentedUser_id , c.comment
```

IF you need results for specific Article, you can add WHERE clause before the GROUP BY section like - WHERE a.id = N

Comment: Ya you are right i am looking for something like that but why you dont use cl.action_like in line 4. and i have only one argument that is "id" from table article

Comment: actually i am trying to fetch all comments of an article. additionally i want to fetch total likes in form of counting action_like column having value "like" related to comments.

Comment: thanks alot @mkRabbani. I really appreciate your perception and work. additionally i really thankfull to you for your count statement and Group by statement. they really increased my knowledge and technicality. thanks alot once again

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend a correlated subquery for this:

```
SELECT a.id as article_id, c.id as comment_id, 
       c.CommentedUser_id, c.comment, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM comment_likes cl
        WHERE cl.comment_id = c.id AND
              cl.action_like = 'like' 
       ) as num_likes
FROM article a INNER JOIN
     comments c
     ON a.id = c.article_id;
```

This is a case where a correlated subquery often has noticeably better performance than an outer aggregation, particularly with the right index.  The index you want is on `comment_likes(comment_id, action_like)`.

Why is the performance better?  Most databases will implement the `group by` by sorting the data.  Sorting is an expensive operation that grows super-linearly -- that is, twice as much data takes more than twice as long to sort.

The correlated subquery breaks the problem down into smaller pieces.  In fact, no sorting should be necessary -- just scanning the index and counting the matching rows.

Comment: Do you have any proof that a correlated subquery **over all the rows** of 2 joined tables does better than conditional aggregation? If so post it.

Comment: @forpas . . . First, I explained the reason why.  Second, did you downvote for this?  Downvoting for such a reason seems like very bad judgement.

Comment: Of course I did. And your explanations is *your explanations*. Do you have any proof?

Comment: Interesting answer, if controversial. I've not seen correlated subqueries recommended before, on the basis they they are not set-based but rather execute for every row. If this breaks it down to smaller pieces, isn't that still an index scan for every row in the articles-comments join? The OP doesn't mention which RDBMS this is for, and they may not be in a position to add an index. You mention the solution does hinge on that index, is it also vendor-dependent? I'd love to see an explain/query plan comparison.

Comment: @Davos . . . (1) Not an index *scan*, but an index *lookup*.  They are different things.  (2) Most databases support index.  There is nothing controversial about this answer, but there is perhaps misunderstanding on how what some people think they know about correlated subqueries.  The answer even explains why correlated subqueries are faster in this case.

Comment: You said "scanning" in your answer, and within each index lookup it will need to count the multiple pointers, which is equivalent to scanning a range of 1. It is not a _single_ index lookup, it will do an index lookup _for each_ comment_id in the comments table. That _for each_ behaviour is entirely consistent with the concerns about correlated subqueries. It is controversial because the answer provides no evidence. There's no algorithmic requirement to sort before grouping. I suspect that there is substance to this answer but it needs supporting DDL, query plans and timings.

Comment: I tested this Querry done by @Gordon Linoff is performance wise really better than the above, it took 0.0067 second while the above one answer by mkRabbani took 0.037 seconds. i really appreciate Gordan Linoff

Comment: But @mkRabanni's  querry is more powerfull, flexible and user oriented. so i like it most

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanakram . . . As the OP, you are free to accept whichever answer you prefer.  I appreciate that you explained your reasoning (even if I disagree).  I appreciate much more that you actually tested the different versions and debunked the myth that correlated subqueries are always bad.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  thanks for appreciation. i am not such experienced in that department. No doubt your recommendation and reasons are totally true, corelated querry in that case is really good in performance. i really like the simplicity and your logic. your querry gives same answer in all cases second on answer but with better performance. now i really need an answer that on which basis you prefer a querry? no doubt now a days everyone needs performance